# Invite friends through Facebook, post to their wall and return to site

Tags: php, facebook, response.redirect, invite

I have created an app for my site in Facebook. While inviting friends to the app, it returns a call back url:

```
> referrals/fb_invite?channel=6&ids[]=100000576230613
```

This leads to a 404 page error.

**What does this URL mean from facebook and how can it be redirected to my site?**

Comment: Where are you seeing that URL? the question doesn't really make sense - are you referring to the URL users land on when accepting a Request sent by your app?

Comment: Its response url from the facebook, after i select a friend for invite it returns to my site with this url attached to my base url.

Answer (score 0):

> I think  this is not an error from facebook.this might be happens only
>   from your side.
>
> > try to change the call back url and use the id retrieved from the facebook.
>
> create the function fb_invite and use retrieved id and pass it.